# Firebird 1.5 Export data to .ini file

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, firebird, text-files, firebird1.5

I need to export entries in a table to an .ini file. I need to set this up as a trigger that is performed each time the table is updated.

So if the fields list for the table is MessengerIPAddress, MessengerPort it would ouput 
[Messenger]
IPAddress=fieldvalue
Port=fieldvalue

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebird event](http://www.firebirdsql.org/doc/whitepapers/events_paper.pdf)